# Calculation in query based on the condition

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package, conditional-statements

I have a package in oracle contains several procedures, in one of those procedures I need to calculate some fee based on specific condition like this:

`if X_flag = 1 
then 
fee = (.5 * orders.total_count) + (.3 * orders.total_amount) 
else 
fee = (.7 * orders.total_count) + (.4 * orders.total_amount)`

so, what is the better way to do that?

---

The procedure that I need to add this calculation on it :

```
procedure informatonRPT ( 
p_customerID in number, 
p_orderID in number)
as
begin 
    select     
        cusromers.costomerId,
        cusromers.costomerName,
        cusromers.coustomerPhone,
        orders.price 

    from       cusromers 
    inner join orders
            on cusromers.orderId = orders.orderID     
    when 
        p_customerID is null or p_customerID = cusromers.costomerId 
        and p_orderID is null or p_orderID = orders.orderID ;

end informatonRPT;
```

customers table columns:

- customerID
- custumerName
- customerPhone
- ordedID

order table columns:

- orderID
- price
- total_Amount
- total_count

**Note that:**
Fee column doesn't exist in the data base, I have to calculate it in query

Comment: I think you need add more information, because first you say, `X_flag` `fee`, `table` and `table_count` but your procedure doesnt have any of those. So where are those field definition?

Comment: where you get `X_flag` ?

Comment: from another table in the data base which I'm not using it in that procedure

Comment: have you check my answer?

Comment: I have to add it as subquery in the same procedure ? or as separated function in the package  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again Im not sure because you didnt provide enought information, but you need use a `CASE` expresion

```
SELECT C.costomerId,
       C.costomerName,
       C.coustomerPhone,
       O.price,
       CASE X_flag 
          WHEN 1 THEN (.5 * O.total_count) + (.3 * O.total_amount) 
          ELSE 7 * O.total_count) + (.4 * O.total_amount)
       END as fee
FROM cusromers C
join orders O
  on C.orderId = O.orderID
```

oracle **[CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)** documentation

Comment: Check my update, probably will make more sense now. Still dont know where `X_flag` came from

Comment: remember accept the answer as correct if solve your problem.